# Absolute URL structure in sub-folder

Tags: php, html, absolute-path, file-structure

So I built out a site on my local machine using MAMP, then I just uploaded it to a web server. Which worked great. But now I'm running into a bit of a problem. I want to be able to work on more sites with MAMP under my /localhost URL. But in that folder, I previously just had my single site files, using /localhost as my project folder. Now I want to be able to have the following URL structure:

```
/localhost
../site1
../site2
../site3
```

etc.

So I moved my site into a folder called site1, within localhost. But then all my urls fall apart. The files that I'm linking to, like css and images, aren't getting referenced properly. Because before, I just did, for example, /img/myimg.jpg to access an image. Or /css/style.css to access a stylesheet. But now those paths to work, I would have to do /site1/css/style.css, for example.

The reason that won't work, is that I want the exact same site structure as on my remote server, so that I can work on my site locally, and then copy the files exactly to upload. But I still want to use absolute paths, because relative paths are messy.

Am I missing something? What's the easiest way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache's virtual hosts, you can find quite good instructions on setting up  virtual hosts in MAMP here http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php or just search for MAMP virtual hosts

The reason your URLs aren't working any more is that they are relative to the document root and you have moved them a level away from the document root.  If you use virtual hosts each site will have its own document root and they should work as expected.